# Calling cmake from a batch script (inside docker)

Tags: docker, batch-file, cmake, msbuild

I want to invoke cmake from a docker file

I have managed to get the command working when I do it manually but want to automate it with a script.

At the moment I call

```
"cmd C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat" x64 8.1
```

which gives me a cmd terminal with 64bit msbuild in the path.

I can then call cmake

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" .
```

The problem is, I have to connect to the container and run these commands manually.

I would like to be able to do something like

```
RUN call vcvarsall.bat" x64 8.1 | cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" .
```

in the `dockerfile`

Comment: I'm wondering if the SHELL command is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want script to be executed when your container is running (not building), you have to put it into `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directives. But if you have piping better put it all into single `bat` file and call this file from Dockerfile

**entrypoint.bat**

```
call vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1 | cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM foo
WORKDIR d:/work
# copy bat file into container
COPY entrypoint.bat d:/work/entrypoint.bat 
ENTRYPOINT ["d:/work/entrypoint.bat"]
```

Thus, after building your image, simply run it with no arguments

```
docker build -t my-image .
docker run my-image   # ENTRYPOINT gets executed here
```

Comment: Trouble is call vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1 | cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" . is exactly the command that does not work, it may be that this is not terminating correctly and so docker is not keeping the cmake output, even if it gets generated

Comment: Remove `call` from the batch file

Comment: In the end, I put the commands I wanted in batch files and invoked the batch files, docker seemed to mangle the strings otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your problem, you want to compile a program during the build procedure of your Dockerfile. Indeed, **vcvarsall.bat** must be executed before any command that make use of the MSVC compiler.

It took me time to figure out what is the proper syntax, but this is my workaround for MSVC2015:

```
SHELL ["\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\"", "amd64", "&&"]
RUN set
```

You will see that all variables set by vcvarsall.bat will be shown (e.g: *VCINSTALLDIR*, *WindowsLibPath*, etc...)